# iOS Launch Screen Asset Catalog not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I believe I am making a silly mistake. But I cannot figure it out.

I have an image named Default.png that I have added to my project. Now when I go to General and then Launch Images I drag and drop this Default.png to the 2x window for my app. When I go to build the project and try it, I get this error:

"The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content."

What's the problem here? I've also seen that simply dragging and dropping the Default.png should do it, but I think that's for older versions.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Also, the image name default.png is now irrelevant. And it doesn't need adding to your project first. It will just take up more space than is necessary. Just drag the image from a folder (desktop for instance) into the asset catalog.

Comment: In my case, LaunchImage was moved in sub-folder and not displaying. So when I moved it back in root folder of asset catalog, it worked fine.

Comment: For XCode 10.1, I solved the issue by giving correct size to launch images. e.g. 1242 × 2688 pixels for XS Max.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Search for LaunchImage keyword in your .plist file and delete it. Then, try assigning the image again by dragging as you already did before...

Comment: I deleted the LaunchImage and created a new one. Which shouldn't have changed anything but it works now. I had a feeling it was something stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

This case raised in Xcode 5.0 + iOS 7. 
Apple use Images.xcassets to group App Icons, App Launch (Default) Images in Xcode 5.0 + iOS 7.

For solving the problem of Asset Catalog Compiler Error
The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content.

**Approach:
Putting suitable size of images into LaunchImage.
For example:
Should be 640x960 dimensioning in iPhone Portrait iOS7 2x.
Should be 640x1136 dimensioning in iPhone Portrait iOS 7 R2.**

Reference from **iOS App Programming Guide**:

**Create and Set iOS Launch Images**

Launch images are displayed while your app is launching on iOS. A launch image matching the device resolution appears as soon as the user taps your app icon.

**App Launch (Default) Images**

Specify the launch images for your app in your Xcode project settings. In Xcode 5.0, specify these images on the General tab of your project settings; in older versions of Xcode, this tab may have a different name. Xcode places your launch image files at the top-level of the app bundle and configures other project settings as appropriate. Specifically, Xcode adds the UILaunchImages key to your app’s Info.plist file automatically if your app runs on iOS 7 or later. That key tells the system the name of your app’s launch image files. For earlier versions of iOS, the system uses the launch image filenames to decide which image to load.

Answer (score 7):

The same error has been resolved by adding the exact sizes of launch images for different iOS devices.

Comment: Yes, if you add a wrong sized image in assets, it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything here, deleted the .app and rebuilt each time, and nothing worked. I finally got fed up and switched back to the old style of launcher image specification (Project Settings Window -> General -> Launch Images -> Source -> Don't use asset catalogs.) That worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. Make sure of a couple of things:

1. Aspect Ratio is what Apple expects, in other words square
2. The sizes are correct, 60pt (for example) should be 60x60
3. 60pt @2x should be 120x120

After I fixed the sizes the app compiled without errors but I think the most important thing is the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with Xcode 7, the `Images.xcassets` was missing from the Build Phases, under Copy Bundle Resources. Then I just added it manually and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the code for "LaunchImage" and rename it to "Default"

Comment: This is what was default. I'm not sure where any code for this would be at. If you do then i'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Check and compare carefully if your image size matches the expected size. In my case I was using a wrong size, but when correcting the project built fine.

[Check this attached image to see where you can compare them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxfcu.png)