# Error while setting app icon and launch image in xcode 5.1

Tags: ios7.1, xcode5.1

I get the following error after dragging an image to set it as app icon and launch image

```
Images.xcassets: The app icon set named "AppIcon" did not have any applicable content.

Images.xcassets: The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484948/ios-launch-screen-asset-catalog-not-working

Comment: @Visput i already checked that.

Comment: I think the reason is improper image size/resolution which caused the issue. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

One of your images could be wrong size (ex: 120x124 instead of 120x120); that can cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove LaunchImage keyword in your .plist file and try again. I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using ImageAssets catalog, I've removed the option for use the catalog from project settings, and used the default name for iOS 7: Default@2x

Hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

One of your icons and one of your splash screen images are not the correct size. I had the same issue and solved it by adding proper sized images for both AppIcon and SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution if you prefer not to use Image sets, you can add the image file to your project and add the following field to your info.plist:

> Icon file: yourIcon.png

Be sure to erase the image from any Image set if you added it before.

BR

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your image sizes. Please re-check the sizes of your 2x and 3x images.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**You need follow the instructions in above image**