# App not sized properly iOS 8 iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I decided to rewrite one of my apps from scratch to clean up the code & perhaps optimize it for iOS 8, but when I run the new version in the iPhone simulator the resolution doesn't seem to be correct.  There is letterboxing around the top and bottom edges of the app, but the old version doesn't have that even when run on the same Xcode 6 simulator.

Even though I'm using the iPhone 5 simulator (which should be 640 x 1136), the output of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` is 640 x 960. Every simulator just seems to be running the app at the iPhone 4 resolution. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS 8. You simply forgot the 4" launch image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How iPhone 5 + iOS6 will decide if an app must be run in letterbox mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include Launch Images for all the resolutions you want to support. Default is only 640 x 960. If you include an image with the resolution of 640 x 1136 as a launch image you will support iPhone5. For iPhone6 and 6Plus include launch images in the correct size. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: So I tried that but now I'm getting: "The launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content."

Comment: Small search might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484948/ios-launch-screen-asset-catalog-not-working

Comment: @fat I was just on that exact page, but there's no reference to the launchimage in my .plist

Comment: Nevermind... the wording was weird and I put the images in the wrong order.

Comment: Don't forget to go into the target and set the "Launch image sources" to whatever your launch image you created is or you'll still get the letterboxing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kz0zp8w7u8l7jr/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2014.38.41.png?dl=0