# Libgdx Robovm StretchViewport not stretching full screen

Tags: camera, libgdx, viewport, robovm

I am trying to stretch the game to fullscreen using StretchViewPort.
The game stretches full screen in android, desktop(tested multiple resolutions) and iPad4(retina).
When i run the same game on iPhone 6 simulator, it is letterboxed on the sides(Landscape).

I tried to assign a viewport manually for testing using this code:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

As per my understanding this must have drawn the game from the left corner edge of the screen. But instead it left a small black space(letterbox size) on the left. Again works exactly as expected with desktop and android versions.

Additional info(Hopefully useful!) I tried getting screen dimensions using

`UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds().getSize()`

The result was:
Screen size: 480.0X320.0

When I tried with `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` 
Screen size: 960X640

The actual device resolution is far greater.

Things I need to know:

1. Why is it not getting stretched to full screen
2. Why is the device resolution returned lower

PS: I am using landscape mode only. Target resolution: 800x480 
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself. It appears I had accidentally deleted the launch screen images from the project. Found the reason and answer here:

[App not sized properly iOS 8 iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043494/app-not-sized-properly-ios-8-iphone-simulator)