# RoboVM - libGDX resizing & FitViewport bug

Tags: ios, libgdx, resize, screen, robovm

I use FitViewport in my libGDX game. it works perfectly on Android & Desktop, but I just can't get it right on iOS.

[the pink box contains the game screen & the black parts are just black like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhZkw.gif)

this is how I initialize the important elements

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(MenuScreen.VIRTUAL_WIDTH,
            MenuScreen.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
    viewport = new FitViewport(MenuScreen.VIRTUAL_WIDTH,
            MenuScreen.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewport.apply();
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2,
            camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    b = new SpriteBatch();
    b.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

MenuScreen.VIRTUAL_WIDTH & HEIGHT are 480 & 800

and this is my resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    renderer.getViewport().update(width, height);
    renderer.camera.position.set(renderer.camera.viewportWidth / 2,
            renderer.camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    renderer.getB().setProjectionMatrix(renderer.getCamera().combined);

}
```

and I am sort of stressed as my license is expiring soon & cannot renew it anymore at RoboVM :S

Comment: This issue is in your iOS platform specific code, not your common code. I can't tell you what your problem is but I would recommend targeting one platform (forget about iOS it's not worth it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody bumps into the same issue, I will leave this link here: [App not sized properly iOS 8 iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043494/app-not-sized-properly-ios-8-iphone-simulator)

I managed to solve it based on the link. I never would have guessed!