# Why would UIScreen.main.bounds return (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0) for every device?

Tags: swift, frame, bounds, uiscreen

Context: I have inherited a legacy app still running in Swift 3, part of the `AppDelegate` looks like this:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // ...some other code here

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        // ...even more other code here

        print(window?.frame, UIScreen.main.bounds)
        return true
    }
```

Regardless of the device used - from iPhone 5S to iPad Pro (3rd gen) - the output is always the following:

```
Optional((0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)) (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why such a thing might happen?

**Update**

Further investigation has revealed that neither the LaunchImages nor LaunchScreen.storyboard are to blame, but instead a directory of pngs that essentially override LaunchScreen.storyboard somehow. The app's UIWindow bound is taken from the dimensions of these pngs somehow!!! I am continuing to investigate further, but if anyone has any ideas in the meanwhile I would be grateful, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not sized properly iOS 8 iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043494/app-not-sized-properly-ios-8-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Your app doesn't have a launch screen.

Comment: Thanks all, am investigating...

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang. I have updated the LaunchImage dir. but that hasn't changed anything

Comment: @rmaddy interestingly (in a boring kind of way) there is a LaunchScreen.storyboard, but the graphics in the launch screen the app is actually using are nothing like those in the storyboard, and updating the storyboard does nothing to change them.

Comment: @rmaddy whilst there was a LaunchScreen.storyboard it wasn't linked to in the General tab of the project. If you want to add that as an answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum The update your put in your question should be removed and posted as an answer below. You found the problem. It's fine for you to post your own answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I found something that helped, but unless I understand how and/or why Xcode was using these PNGs I can't justify calling it an answer, and I don't have the time to investigate further